# Android video capture by giving control to built-in video support

Tags: android, video, camera, android-mediarecorder

I am developing an application in which I want to capture a video in which control is given to Native camera activity without getting the control to my Application. I mean i dont want to create MediaRecorder object. Just call the Camera and it capture Video and return the Path of the Video (Using ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE).
Can any one suggest a Tutorial to do so